# Accessing Gmail and Google Sheets using a Python Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I am trying to automate reading my Gmail once a day to access a specific email, extract some information and add it to one of my Google Sheets. I was able to write Python scripts on my local machine to access my Gmail and Google Sheets using the respective APIs. Now I want to automate this using a Cloud Function but I am not sure how to go about the authentication. From my Google search and looking for answers on SO, it seems like using a service account is ideal for automating this as it's a server-to-server communication. However, all the guides I have found so far are JavaScript based, and I wanted to know if this is doable using Python. If not, maybe this is a good time for me to start learning JS! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you share the tutorials you have found? Cloud Function Supports Both Javascript and Python (version 3), so you should be able to do the same operations with either of them. Given that you already have a working python script a few adaptations to it should do the trick, but we would need more details on how you are doing that, and what tutorial you are following in order to answer that.

Comment: I found these two tutorials:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/intelligent-gmail-processing/index.html#0
https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-oauth-gmail

Comment: All of the samples in the tutorials you shared are language independent, the only reason they are in javascript is because GCP uses node.js as the main language it supports, even though it supports many other, including python. I would say that you could use the same code you already have and follow those steps and it would work.